# OpenDKIM / Postfix sign console-sent mail, but not from a mail client / SMTP

Tags: postfix, dkim, opendkim

I have Postfix running on a Debian 9 machine, and installed opendkim  (both from the Debian repositories). The milter socket/connection is inet:localhost:8892, and the iptables firewall allows that connection (a `telnet localhost 8892` succeeds).

However, I only get signed messages if I send e-mail from the console (with `mail -s "testing DKIM" my-address@not-the-same-domain`), but not if I send it from Thunderbird.  Notice, with Thunderbird, I use ssh tunneling, so that the mail server sees the connection as originating from localhost. (that is, on my desktop, I run `ssh -Llocalhost:2525:my-server:25 tunnel@my-server`, and I tell Thunderbird that the outgoing mail server is localhost, port 2525.

This is an example of the signature I get when sending from the console:

```
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=simple/simple; d=[omitted -- but it shows the correct domain];
    s=mail; t=1557228588;
    bh=slJTHzrIw+6TkIIPpFmGER34xtLwMLZ2md99gvHoFTE=;
    h=To:Subject:Date:From:From;
    b=jtOM5OOM83l [ ··· several lines of "gibberish" ··· ] 4qdpSt4l86DEA==
```

Any ideas on what could be causing this issue?

**[[EDIT]]** The problem gets more puzzling. While inspecting the logs, I noticed a warning `external host XXXX.my-service-provider.com` attempted to send as `my-domain.com`

I adjusted `/etc/hosts`, `/etc/hostname` ... Finally I realized that I had to adjust the reverse DNS lookup, and I did that.  Now, the command `hostname` responds with the FQDN (the correct domain for which I'm configuring DKIM).

Now, in `/var/log/syslog` when I send an e-mail, I'm getting the message `external host *the-correct-FQDN* attempted to send as *the-correct-FQDN*`. And the transmitted message does not contain a DKIM signature.

If I do `telnet localhost 25`, greet the SMTP server with `helo the-correct-FQDN`, the message is DKIM-signed; the logs show that a connection from `localhost (127.0.0.1)` was responsible for the transmission.

Any ideas?
**[[ END EDIT ]]**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the issue was caused by a lack of a InternalHosts parameter.  For the current version of opendkim on Debian 9 (2.11), I solved it as follows:

Edited file `/etc/opendkim.conf` and added the following line:

```
InternalHosts file:/etc/opendkim-trustedhosts.conf
```

Then, the file `/etc/opendkim-trustedhosts.conf` contains:

```
127.0.0.1
x.x.x.x (the actual public IP of the server)
```

And voilà --- restart and that fixed the problem!

Some differences I noticed w.r.t. other info I found out there --- from what I could see, on CentOS (not sure whether older versions or still like this), the default configuration is: there is a directory `etc/opendkim`, and inside that directory there is, among others, a file `TrustedHosts.conf`;  the file `/etc/opendkim.conf` already has the `InternalHosts` directive pointing to the TrustedHosts file.  On Debian 9, one has to create it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Similar problem and context: using openDKIM with Postfix as MTA that is then a relay only for authenticated Mail User Agents (MUA's), the later counting notably MS-Outlook clients configured with SMTP+POP or SMTP+IMAP connexions to the Postfix MTA over TLS/SSL + SASL (authentication with login and password) through port 587 in my case.

When local console 'mailx' or 'sendmail' is used, the openDKIM integration is controlled through the *non_smtpd_milters* option in *postfix/main.cf*, whereas *smtpd_milters* option do control the case of incoming SMTPD e-mails from authenticated MUA's. So first you may need to check that both options are aligned, e.g. like

```
smtpd_milters = inet:127.0.0.1:8891
non_smtpd_milters = $smtpd_milters
```

Then, when a valid DKIM signature is generated for local e-mails (via 'mailx' or 'sendmail') but not on e-mails from authenticated MUA's, it is most likely an issue with determining who is the message sender and thus preventing openDKIM to crawl to the 'From:' domain for which the signature is setup. You may likely found traces like:

```
opendkim[9530]: E3B6A13CBED: can't determine message sender;
```

which in my case was due to an interference with the *header_checks* option in Postfix. Look for it in either main.cf or master.cf (which can override options in main.cf), e.g.

```
-o header_checks=regexp:/etc/postfix/submission_header_cleanup
```

and ensure the associateed header cleanup rules will **NOT** contain a regex like:

```
/^Received:/            IGNORE
```

which you must then comment-OUT or remove.

Last, ensure *postfix/main.cf* will tell Postfix to pass sufficient data to opendkim through the milter protocol with an option like:

```
milter_mail_macros =  i {mail_addr} {client_addr} {client_name} {auth_type} {auth_authen}
```